# 97 Sentra Slow Acceleration?

Tags: nissan, acceleration

I just recently bought a 97 Sentra with less than 15k on it. I have never driven a Sentra before, so I'm not even sure if there is a problem. There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of power and I have to really give it some gas up hills.

Now this could just be the little 1.6L inline, 115 HP engine. Especially because I was borrowing a Mini cooper while I looked for a car, which is much sportier.

I have no problem getting up to speed (on flat surfaces) at it does 80+ fine. I just don't want to floor it so it takes 45 seconds or so to get to 65.

I've changed the plugs/oil/tires and air filter. I'll do the fuel filter next.

Would flooring it 0-60 in 10 seconds be a good test if the car is accelerating as it should? (That is what it is rated for.)

Comment: Has it been sitting a long time? 15k miles is next to nothing for a 97 of any make/model. You are right that 115hp is not a bunch. I wouldn't expect too much out of it.

Comment: No sitting too long. She had driven it regularly (just not far) until she was unable to continue driving about ~1 year ago. I'm guessing it's just the small engine too. I'll see what my 0-60 time is and check back.

Comment: With as old as it is, I'd do an upper end treatment with something like Seafoam and also consider changing out the O2 sensors.

Comment: With an engine that size... yeah, expect little power

Comment: Thanks all, it seems like it's normal - I'm just not used to a small efficient engine. I'm not hating the ~38 MPG avg either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did fine on the 0-60, so it's just a small engine. I'll Seafoam it anyways, wouldn't hurt. O2 sensors should be fine, it passed smog with flying colors.

Comment: My little truck gets from 0-60 in 6.5. But then, it has a 5.9l v8 in it, and gets 10 mpg.

Comment: There is nothing "little" about your truck, J. :D

Comment: Musser, I have a 1.6L and get to 0-60 in 10. 38 to the gallon average so far. I'll spend the extra 3.5 seconds accelerating for that trade off :).